# What's the difference between PAM auth interface and account interface

Tags: linux, authentication, redhat, pam

In a Redhat documentation (found in [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/managing_smart_cards/pam_configuration_files) link), under the section `PAM Module Interfaces` it states that `auth` interface of a PAM module is used for authenticating the use. And the use of `account` interface is for verifying the access is allowed or not.

Is there a clear difference between these two interfaces or can they be used instead of one another?

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on Server Fault.

Comment: Auth: Prove who you are. Account: Grant what you can do.

Comment: So Auth is for Authentication and Account is for Authorization?

Answer (score 3):

**Difference Between auth and account**

**auth**
 - This module interface authenticates use. For example, it requests and verifies the validity of a password. Modules with this interface can also set credentials, such as group memberships or Kerberos tickets.

**account** -
 This module interface verifies that access is allowed. For example, it checks if a user account has expired or if a user is allowed to log in at a particular time of day.

> To answer the question of if they can be interchanged,
>
> Example:
>       User 'Adam' tried to log in and both auth and account interfaces are set, then Interface 'account' will check if 'Adam' has rights and
>   privileges to login or not, if yes then, interface 'auth' will check
>   if the password entered is correct or not.

```
Pam Manual can be followed by typing 'man pam' on terminal -- shown below

   account - provide account verification types of service: has the user's password expired?; is
   this user permitted access to the requested service?

   authentication - authenticate a user and set up user credentials. Typically this is via some
   challenge-response request that the user must satisfy: if you are who you claim to be please
   enter your password. Not all authentications are of this type, there exist hardware based
   authentication schemes (such as the use of smart-cards and biometric devices), with suitable
   modules, these may be substituted seamlessly for more standard approaches to authentication -
   such is the flexibility of Linux-PAM.
```